# Unable to run gcloud in cloudfunctions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

here is my cloud function code(using pyhton 3.9),

```
import os
import subprocess


def is_gcloud_accessible():
    command = ["which", "gcloud"]
    try:
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
        print(result)
        return result.stdout.strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        return False


def trigger_dataflow_flex_template(req):
    project_id = "dataflow-396318"
    location = "us-central1"
    template_gcs_path = "gs://abc/templates/finalflextemplate.json"

    if not is_gcloud_accessible():
        print("The gcloud command is not accessible.")
        return "The gcloud command is not accessible."

    command = [
        "gcloud",  # Use "gcloud" instead of the full path
        "dataflow",
        "flex-template",
        "run",
        "my-job-name",
        "--template-file-gcs-location",
        template_gcs_path,
        "--project",
        project_id,
        "--region",
        location,
    ]

    try:
        print(command)
        result = subprocess.run(command, capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
        return f"Command output: {result.stdout}"
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        return f"Command failed with error: {e.stderr}"
```

requirements.txt

```
gcloud
```

in cloud shell working fine but when i run same thing in cloud functions "gcloud" is not found or if i give bin path not accessable e.t.c

am strugling since 3 days on this. please suggest me and be a savior

Comment: Why do you expect gcloud to be available in Cloud Functions? Cloud Functions is not an operating system with commands and utilities. Consider using Google Cloud Run instead.

Comment: I want to trigger my flex-template which will create a data flow for every 15 minutes. Help me with any better approach

Comment: See Doug's answer for good options. My preference is Cloud Run due to the simplicity of development, ease of deployment, and very low cost.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions system images do not come with gcloud installed.

Instead, you can use something other than Cloud Functions that gives you the ability to create the system image you want (using docker), with all the executables you need.  Cloud Run and Compute Engine can do that.

Also consider if there are maybe APIs you can call directly instead of accessing them through gcloud.  If you are using Dataflow, look at the [Dataflow API docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest).

Comment: API call in the right solution, the GCLOUD CLI is only a wrapper. To have more insight on the API call(s) performed by the CLI, use the `--log-http` flag to log all the API calls